# How to resolve Rows were rejected while reading from external source(s) in sqlserver Data warehouse

Tags: azure-data-lake, sql-data-warehouse, azure-synapse

I have to load the data from datalake to sql server data warehouse using the polybase tables.I have created the set up for the creation of external tables.i have created the external table and trying to do select * from ext_t1 table but i'm getting the error as Rows were rejected while reading from external source(s).Below is my external table script.Can some help me on this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[EXT_TEST1]
( A VARCHAR(10),B VARCHAR(20)) 
(DATA_SOURCE = [Azure_Datalake],LOCATION = N'/A/Test_CSV/',FILE_FORMAT =csvfileformat,REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,REJECT_VALUE = 1)
```

Table got created but after querying the select statement i'm getting the below issue
Rows were rejected while reading from external source(s). 
2 rows rejected from external table [EXT_TEST1] in plan step 2 of query execution:
    Location: '/A/Test_CSV/abc.csv' Column ordinal: 1, Expected data type: VARCHAR(20) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.
    Location: '/A/Test_CSV/abc.csv' Column ordinal: 1, Expected data type: VARCHAR(20) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Comment: External tables are supported only from SQL Server 2016 onwards. You are using SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Venkataraman- Thanks for your reply.I'm using the supported sql server only

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try below things. Also, see the different appraoches to [troubleshooting polybase issues from SQL CAT Team](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/DataCAT/PolyBase-Setup-Errors-and-Possible-Solutions/ba-p/305297?advanced=false&collapse_discussion=true&q=polybase%20error&search_type=thread)

- As you are having strict Rejection, you are getting error, even if
  there is a problem with single row. I would suggest you to increase
  to big number and see whether data is loading successfully for other
  rows.
- I would suggest you to check the csv file, also check the
  csvfileformat, whether file format definition is proper. If the file
  is having quoted strings, then you have to specify accordingly.
- It could be data format issue also. There could be rows, where a
  comma is missing and due to that, you are getting bigger string than
  VARCHAR(20) and you are getting data truncation issues Or your
  datatype VARCHAR(20) is not sufficient to hold the values. I would
  suggest you to define the datatype accordingly.

On further search, the error is due to Data truncation. You have not allocated sufficient length for the CSV values. Taken from [Polybase to non-relational data](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/azure-dwh-part-14-polybase-to-access-to-non-relational-data-1)

> Msg 107090, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 Query aborted-- the maximum
>   reject threshold (0 rows) was reached while reading from an external
>   source: 1 rows rejected out of total 1 rows processed.
>   (/prices.csv)Column ordinal: 2, Expected data type: VARCHAR(4) collate
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Offending value: price  (Column
>   Conversion Error), Error: String or binary data would be truncated.
>   This error occurs when the data is truncated. You may need to modify
>   the data type or the number of characters supported. for example, if
>   the value has 4 characters, and your data type is varchar(2) you will
>   need to change to varchar(4).